# open access database with companies/large employers registered in a given city in US

Tags: data-request, usa, city

Is anyone aware of an open access database with companies/large employers registered in a given city in US, specifying registration date (office opening).

Comment: Please [edit] and define *large*. And you probably will not be able to get *office opening* dates, but only *registration dates*. I'm not aware of how things work in the US, but where would they (have to) be registered - don't these institutiosn have resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenCorporates data](https://opencorporates.com/info/bulk_core_legal_entity_data) is the closest dataset that I know of. It includes the registration information for many U.S. states, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair amount of corporate registration data on Enigma Public (disclaimer: I work there and legitimately vouch for it). It's organized on a state by state basis but you should be able to see the city where a business is registered within the dataset. Here's [California](https://public.enigma.com/datasets/california-corporate-registrations/613a3195-cc43-4614-8ce9-c19d77fc2327), [Texas](https://public.enigma.com/datasets/texas-corporate-registrations-master-file/801e43b1-27d8-4d71-888c-de3bc0253209) and [New York](https://public.enigma.com/datasets/new-york-corporate-registrations-active/f6cb6ee9-fcd9-4020-b972-d49a2185c8b3). We definitely have other states too - I would just search 'Corporate Registration' in Public's search engine and see what comes up.